# Newby: Java tutorial, errors when i try to calculate an integer?! help please

Tags: java, eclipse

this is doing my head in so bad. I am a beginner trying to create my own basic program based from a java tutorial but with some extra calculations and i can't work out what is wrong.

There are no errors within the code, only get an error when i try to run it. I just want to prinln the Distance of a golf ball traveled and to calculate the speed per second based on an time. It's just for my own learning. But i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at GolfBall.<init>(GolfBall.java:23)
    at GolfCalc.main(GolfCalc.java:6)
```

For some reason it reads my 'minute and 'second as zero when it tries to calculate even though they have been assigned values, "playerA.timeSecond(28);" etc . If i remove the code where it makes the calculation and just have a 'System.out.println(minute + "/" + second) to try and debug what is going on, it reads it fine and displays the proper values. Only when it tries to calculate it it gets the error... i dont understand what is going wrong.

*note if i change just the ' int minute = 0; to 'int minute = 1; it will run but the value will print as 0 after it does the calculation!?

My code:

```
class GolfBall {

    //Instantiating as integers
    int distance = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;


    void travel(int newValue) {
        distance = newValue;
    }

    void timeMin(int newValue){
        minute = newValue;
    }

    void timeSecond(int newValue){
        second = newValue;
    }


    int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal

    void printStates(){
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance 
                + " Speed: " + speed +" Metres per second");
    }

}
```

And main class where i assigned the values and such:

```
public class GolfCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args){


    GolfBall playerA = new GolfBall();
    GolfBall playerB = new GolfBall();

    playerA.travel(423); // My assigned values
    playerA.timeMin(1);
    playerA.timeSecond(28);
    playerA.printStates();

    playerB.travel(397);
    playerB.timeMin(1);
    playerB.timeSecond(13);
    playerB.printStates ();

   }

}
```

Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: In `int time = (60 / minute) + second;` shouldn't that be `*` instead of `/` ?

Comment: Can you correct your code listing please? the lines starting with int time = (60 / minute)... is not within a method.

Comment: @JamesB That part is perfectly fine. Field initialization doesn't have to be in a method.

Comment: @user3580294 True it doesn't but the problem is due to this initialisation which divides by 0 - that is the point I am making.

Comment: @JamesB I know. But that's not what you said the problem is in your initial comments.

Comment: Do you Know Anything about [`CONSTRUCTOR`](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors)?

Comment: TAsk - i am going through tutorials from java site and haven't come across constructors yet. I just was trying to work out what i was doing wrong. But with everyones help, i now know exactly what went wrong. Thank you all

Comment: David Wallace - (60 * minute) would give me 60 * the value, i was calculating into seconds not into hours, so need to divide 60 into minute value :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dividing by 0 in this line

```
int time = (60 / minute) + second;
```

This line is executed the moment you create a GolfBall object and at that time `minute` is still 0.

EDIT:

You could solve this issue by moving two lines to the `void printState()` method as follows:

```
void printStates(){
    int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
    System.out.println("Distance: " + distance 
            + " Speed: " + speed +" Metres per second");
}
```

This ensures the code is only executed when the method is called. In the previous scenario the code was executed at the same moment the lines `int minute = 0;` and `int second = 0;` were executed.

Comment: How can i execute it after i have assigned it a value?

Comment: or just can't use integer, something else?

Comment: @user3796133 I have edited my answer to include a (possible solution).

Answer (score 4):

Just move the calculations into your `printStates` method and remove the class fields:

```
void printStates(){
    int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
    System.out.println("Distance: " + distance 
            + " Speed: " + speed +" Metres per second");
}
```

Your current code does the calculation only once, when the `GolfBall` class is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
```

The thing is that this is evaluated *when you instantiate a `GolfBall` object*. `minute` and `second` are initialized to `0`, as all class fields are, and so you end up with a division by 0.

It might make it a bit clearer to rearrange your fields. The code here is equivalent to your original code:

```
class GolfBall {

    //Instantiating as integers
    int distance = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal

    // methods follow...
}
```

Now do you see where the division by 0 comes from? The fact that you call `timeMin()` doesn't matter because you divide by 0 before object instantiation even finishes!

---

One way of solving this is setting `time` and `speed` to 0 and recalculating whenever you set `distance`, `minute`, or `second`. Alternatively, you can simply calculate directly in the `printStates()` method.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realise that the int are immediately set to 0 when it runs the code, i will try in the Println, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
```

in these line of code you cannot divide 60 by minute...(what if minute is equal to 0)

so you will get ->`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

make below variables 1

```
   int distance = 0;
        int minute = 0;
        int second = 0;
```

Comment: I thought i could assigned it a value then execute it, but it seems it's execute from immediately.

Comment: yes most probably.
if it does not make any problem of your code, equals them to one

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
```

is executed the when you instantiate your GolfBall object.

You shoud put that code in a method and call it after you cal travel(), timeMin() and  timeSecond()

Answer (score 0):

This is some pretty odd tutorial with this naming convention you're using....

```
public class GolfBall 
{

    //Instantiating as integers
    int distance = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;


    public void setDistance(int newValue) 
    {
        distance = newValue;
    }

    public void setMinute(int newValue)
    {
        minute = newValue;
    }

    public void setSecond(int newValue)
    {
        second = newValue;
    }

    public void printStates()
    {
        int time = (60 * minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
        double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal

        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance 
                + " Speed: " + speed +" Metres per second");
    }
}
```

And

```
public class GolfCalc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GolfBall playerA = new GolfBall();
        GolfBall playerB = new GolfBall();

        playerA.setDistance(423); // My assigned values
        playerA.setMinute(1);
        playerA.setSecond(28);
        playerA.printStates();

        playerB.setDistance(397);
        playerB.setMinute(1);
        playerB.setSecond(13);
        playerB.printStates();
   }
}
```

Comment: Although technically you are still going to get an arithmetic division by zero exception if minute and second are both zero.

Comment: Well, im knew here, im not sure. I meant it was based from a tutroial

Comment: I know :D it's just odd that they named things "timeMin" instead of something like "setMinute" as the convention goes for setters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
 double speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
```

In your case, the calculation is done in the constructor, where all vavriables are initialised with 0. Do the following:

```
class GolfBall {

    //Instantiating as integers
    int distance = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;

int time = 0;
double speed = 0;


    void travel(int newValue) {
        distance = newValue;
    }

    void timeMin(int newValue){
        minute = newValue;
    }

    void timeSecond(int newValue){
        second = newValue;
    }

public void calc(){
time = (60 / minute) + second; // To calculate total time into seconds
    speed = distance / time;  //double as the result will be a decimal
}

    void printStates(){
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance 
                + " Speed: " + speed +" Metres per second");
    }

    }
```

Class GolfCalc:

```
public class GolfCalc {

        public static void main(String[] args){

    GolfBall playerA = new GolfBall();
    GolfBall playerB = new GolfBall();

    playerA.travel(423); // My assigned values
    playerA.timeMin(1);
    playerA.timeSecond(28);
    playerA.calc();
    playerA.printStates();

    playerB.travel(397);
    playerB.timeMin(1);
    playerB.timeSecond(13);
    playerB.calc();
    playerB.printStates ();

   }

}
```